# php rounding in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

round() function is used for decimal like 5,5 -> 6 and 5,3 -> 5, and i have problem with milion numbers.
For Example :
i have number like 35000001, how to make that number to be 3500000 and 69999 to be 70000

Comment: you can try rounding your number/10 and multiply the result by 10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834537/how-to-round-down-to-the-nearest-significant-figure-in-php The answers to this question should help you.

Answer (score 2):

`$a = round($a / 10) * 10`

You can change 10 to be 100, 1000, etc in order to round to a bigger degree.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `round` function in the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php):

```
<?php
    echo round(3.4);         // 3
    echo round(3.5);         // 4
    echo round(3.6);         // 4
    echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
    echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
    echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
    echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
    echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
?>
```

Perhaps what you want is:

```
echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
```