# How to convert 11,22,33 into 10, 20 and 30 in PHP?

Tags: php, numbers, int

I don't know how to title the question correctly (please tell me what this kind of number called).

I'd like to convert from 2 digits number into a 10 divisible number. For example, I expect:

- 15 to become 10
- 23 to become 20
- 38 to become 30
- 999 to become 900
- 9999 to become 9000

I tried searching for the solution on google but I don't know how to type the proper word.

Comment: You should convert it to a float by dividing by 10(00,ect..) then convert it to an int and multiply it again by the same number you use to divide

Answer (score 3):

Easy, use the PHP floor function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

```
floor($number/10) * 10
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple function should work:

```
<?php
function roundDown($var){
    $len = strlen($var)-1;
    $divide = 1;
    for($i=1;$i<=$len;$i++){
        $divide .= 0;
    }


    return floor($var/$divide)*$divide;
}

echo roundDown(9999);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is divide by ten, then floor value and multiply by ten. [(Floor method - phpdocs)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)

```
floor($number/10)*10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `round`:

`echo round(1241757, -6); // 1000000`

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the "one significant figure".
I think this answer provides a good solution:

[How to round down to the nearest significant figure in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834537/how-to-round-down-to-the-nearest-significant-figure-in-php)

Short form:

```
$x = $y - $y % pow(10, floor(log10($y)));
```