# Format number to N significant digits in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to format (round) float (double) numbers to lets say 2 significant digits for example like this:

```
1        => 1
11       => 11
111      => 110
119      => 120
0.11     => 0.11
0.00011  => 0.00011
0.000111 => 0.00011
```

So the arbitrary precision remains same

I expect there is some nice function for it already built in, but could not find any so far

I was pointed to [How to round down to the nearest significant figure in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834537/how-to-round-down-to-the-nearest-significant-figure-in-php), which is close but doesn't work for N significant digits and I'm not sure what it does with 0.000XXX numbers

Comment: So what is your question? Do you want us to find or write the function for you?

Comment: If you know there is one, please tell me. I would prefer not to write it on my own, since I'm sure it was written before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round down to the nearest significant figure in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834537/how-to-round-down-to-the-nearest-significant-figure-in-php)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get a number rounded to n significant figures you need to find the size of the number in powers of ten, and subtract that from n.

This works fine for simple rounding:

```
function sigFig($value, $digits)
{
    if ($value == 0) {
        $decimalPlaces = $digits - 1;
    } elseif ($value < 0) {
        $decimalPlaces = $digits - floor(log10($value * -1)) - 1;
    } else {
        $decimalPlaces = $digits - floor(log10($value)) - 1;
    }

    $answer = round($value, $decimalPlaces);
    return $answer;
}
```

This will give the following:
0.0001234567 returns 0.0001235
123456.7 returns 123500

However a value such as 10 to four significant figures should strictly be represented as 10.00 to signify the precision to which the value is known.

If this is the desired output you can use the following:

```
function sigFig($value, $digits)
{
    if ($value == 0) {
        $decimalPlaces = $digits - 1;
    } elseif ($value < 0) {
        $decimalPlaces = $digits - floor(log10($value * -1)) - 1;
    } else {
        $decimalPlaces = $digits - floor(log10($value)) - 1;
    }

    $answer = ($decimalPlaces > 0) ?
        number_format($value, $decimalPlaces) : round($value, $decimalPlaces);
    return $answer;
}
```

Now 1 is displayed as 1.000

Comment: thanks for taking you time, we switched to your solution

Comment: The only place this breaks down is when the number exceeds the default printf precision exponent, and NANs. For example, I don't know why, but if I wanted to print 6.02e23 with 1 digit, I'd like 600000000000000000000000. Minor detail though. :)

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the code: 

sigFig(0.9995, 3) outputs 1.000

Whereas the output should be 1.00, e.g. according to https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/sig-fig

Comment: sigFig(9.9995, 3) outputs 10.00 instead of 10.0. Fixed it by adding

if (floor(log10($value, $decimalPlaces)) !== floor(log10(round($value, $decimalPlaces)))) {
        $decimalPlaces--;
      }

Answer (score 1):

With little modification to possible duplicate, answer by Todd Chaffee:

```
public static function roundRate($rate, $digits)
{
    $mod = pow(10, intval(round(log10($rate))));
    $mod = $mod / pow(10, $digits);
    $answer = ((int)($rate / $mod)) * $mod;
    return $answer;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired result. It rounds down, or floors the answer, rather than rounding and It doesn't allow for negative numbers.
Also the number of significant figures is inconsistent:
 roundRate(3.333, 2) returns 3.3 whilst roundRate(2.222, 2) returns 2.22

Answer (score -1):

To make sigFig(0.9995, 3) output 1.00, use

if(floor(log10($value)) !== floor(log10(round($value, $decimalPlaces)))) {$decimalPlaces--;}

Said line of code should be placed before declaring $answer.

If input $value is negative, set a flag and remove the sign at the beginning of the function, like this:

if($value < 0){$flag = 1;}
$value = ltrim($value, "-");

Then right before returning $answer, detect if the flag is set and if so restore the negative sign, like this:

if(isset($flag)){$answer = "-".$answer;}

Finally, for result values with ambiguous number of significant digits (e.g., 1000, 12000,...), express the result in scientific notation to the desired number of significant digits using sprintf or printf.