# Round numbers to n number of decimals

Tags: php, decimal, rounding

**Question:**

What I need is a way or a function in PHP to round a number with a variable amount of decimals to a value that can be relevant for cost calculations.

It makes no sense to know that a product cost is 0.00023123414123 USD/g when instead 0.00023 USD/g leads to a very similar, more practical cost. When working with small amounts of something, being too accurate is inefficient. I couldn't pay 0.000231234141 USD for something and unless I buy more than a 1000 kg, 0.000231234141 isn't better than 0.000231

**Context:**

I'm working on a project for a restaurant and I need to calculate a product cost and display the result as price/unit. The thing is that depending on the unit selected by the user, the result could be either 0.25 USD/kg or 0.00025 USD/g. So I cannot use round($var, 2) because I don't know how many decimals expect

I store the price and the amount in different columns of the DB and perform the math only for displaying the result

**Making it answerable:**

Let's assume that the user buys 17kg of chicken at a price of 36 USD and record the expense in the DB. The cost of the product will be around $36/17kg = 2.117647058 USD/kg wich I can round to let's say 2.11 USD/kg, so far so good. But now if the user wants to know the cost/gram of the product, then is the same math (in this case code) divide the money/amount of product and the I will have $36/17000g = 0.002117647058 wich obviuosly cannot be rounded to the same amount of decimals than the first case.

So I need a way to always round the result to a clean number.

For example:

0.002117647058 => 0.0021

2.117647058 => 2.12

Comment: This question needs work to be answerable. [Please follow this guide to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: dont round and store, round only on display (store exact value), then you can reverse without issues, plus over a year them fractions add up

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, thanks I edited the question: I store the price and the amount in different columns of the DB and do the math only for displaying the result

Comment: Floats are almost never clean, regardless of how many digits they have.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know, I just need to get rid of the excess of decimals before displaying the number. This project is for a small, local bussines so they are not expending millions of dolar, thus an extremedly accurate number makes no sense in practice.

Comment: What you seem to want is a function to round to n significant figures: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618679/format-number-to-n-significant-digits-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number to N significant digits in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618679/format-number-to-n-significant-digits-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a function which looks for 0.n and then returns the iteration value + `$min`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Get the decimals value
 * 
 * @param $value
 * @param $min  - min decimals
 * @return int
 */
function get_decimals($value = 0, $min = 2) {
    if ($value === '0.00') {
        return $min;
    }
    for ($i = strlen($value); $i >= $min; $i--) {
        if (strstr($value, '0.'.str_repeat('0', $i), true) !== false) {
            return $i+$min;
        }
    }
    return $min;
}
```

So `get_float('0.002117647058')` would return 4, which can then be used in number_format.

**For example:**

```
$values = [
    '0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001', # ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    '0.002117647058',
    '0.00000000001',
    '2.117647058',
    '999.0',
    '0.1',
    '0.00',
    '0.0',
    '0'
];

foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo number_format($value, get_decimals($value)).PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Result:**

```
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
0.0021
0.000000000010
2.12
999.00
0.10
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

https://3v4l.org/bmMNe

Or `$min` 5:

```
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000
0.00212
0.000000000010000
2.11765
999.00000
0.10000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
```

https://3v4l.org/eD7Gi

Answer (score 1):

You can use round if the number is >1 and regex if it's smaller.

```
$num = [2.117647058, 0.002117647058];

foreach($num as $n){
    if(substr($n,0,1) > 0){
        echo round($n, 2) . "\n";
    }else{
        preg_match("/([0\.]+)(\d{1,2})/", $n, $m);
        echo $m[0] . "\n";
    }
}
```

The regex pattern matches the 0's and dot then the next one or two following digits.

https://3v4l.org/UJ6W1