# How to round / format long numbers with zeros?

Tags: php, math, numbers, format, rounding

I am having a variety of long numbers and I am trying to write a function to format them correctly. Can someone help me out?

I already tried "`number_format()`" and "`round()`" but that doesn't solve my problems..

I would like to round it like following:

```
1024.43  --> 1,024.43  
0.000000931540 --> 0.000000932  
0.003991 --> 0.00399  
0.3241 --> 0.324
1045.3491 --> 1,045.35
```

So that means, If number is bigger than "0" it should round to 2 decimal places and add thousands seperator (like 6,554.24) AND if number less than "1" it should round to 3 digits whenever numbers appear after the zeros (for example 0.0003219 to 0.000322 OR 0.2319 to 0.232)

EDIT:
The same should apply to "-" values. For example:

```
-1024.43  --> -1,024.43  
-0.000000931540 --> -0.000000932  
-0.003991 --> -0.00399  
-0.3241 --> -0.324
-1045.3491 --> -1,045.35
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Nope, because that question is _significant digits_, which means that `111` turns into `110`, which the OP doesn't want. The OP's number format seems to be a very unique and specialized format which I can't fathom why he'd need :)

Comment: @Davіd we can easily take that function and change it handling when number > 0 and when number < 0. For `>0` case, `number_format` is enough; else the custom function described

Comment: do you have any try yourself? plz post

Comment: I think the question separates numbers that are smaller and bigger than 1, not 0. Am I right?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya So you admit that it's not an exact duplicate? Also, further reading on duplicates: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled _"Questions may be duplicates if they have the **same (potential) answers**. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words."_

Comment: yea Sorry. Smaller than 1 ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48283297/2469308

- handle this in two separate cases.
- for numbers between -1 and 1; we need to calculate the number of digits to round. And then, using [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function we can get the result.
- for else, simply use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)() function with decimal digits set to 2.

Try the following:

```
function customRound($value)
{
   if ($value > -1 && $value < 1) {

       // define the number of significant digits needed
       $digits = 3;

       if ($value >= 0) {

           // calculate the number of decimal places to round to
           $decimalPlaces = $digits - floor(log10($value)) - 1;
       } else {

           $decimalPlaces = $digits - floor(log10($value * -1)) - 1;
       }

       // return the rounded value
       return number_format($value, $decimalPlaces);

   } else {

      // simply use number_format function to show upto 2 decimal places
      return number_format($value, 2);
    } 

    // for the rest of the cases - return the number simply
    return $value;
}
```

### [Rextester DEMO](http://rextester.com/KDVPI71007)

Comment: Thank You. Thats great so far and seems to work. Just 2 Problems: If the number is too small, it outputs like this "8.54E-5" and can this script also work with negative numbers? Thank You!

Comment: @N1njaWTF check the edited answer. it should handle very low values > 0. How should it look for negative numbers ? please edit your question to show sample output for negative numbers also

Comment: Great! That worked perfectly. I have edited my answer. :) It should basically format the same way if there is a "-" before the number. thank you.

Comment: @N1njaWTF please check the updated answer. I have also added rextester demo. should work perfectly fine for you :-)

Comment: Great man!! Perfectly works! I've made a small edit, so it also outputs the number "0" :) Thank You so much dude! http://rextester.com/PYYT9914

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = 123.456;
echo number_format($x, max(2, 3 - ceil(log10(abs($x))))) . "\n";
$x = 1.23456;
echo number_format($x, max(2, 3 - ceil(log10(abs($x))))) . "\n";
$x = 0.0123456;
echo number_format($x, max(2, 3 - ceil(log10(abs($x))))) . "\n";
$x = 0.0000123456;
echo number_format($x, max(2, 3 - ceil(log10(abs($x))))) . "\n";
$x = 0.000000123456;
echo number_format($x, max(2, 3 - ceil(log10(abs($x))))) . "\n";
$x = 0.00000000123456;
echo number_format($x, max(2, 3 - ceil(log10(abs($x))))) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
123.45
1.23
0.0123
0.0000123
0.000000123
0.00000000123
```

Basically this always keeps a minimal of 2 decimal digits up to 3 significant digits.

However, because of the way floating point is handled internally (as power of 2 and not 10), there are some catches. Numbers like `0.1` and `0.001` and so forth can't be stored precisely, so they are actually stored as `0.09999999...` or things like that. In cases like this it may seem like it is computing things wrong and give you answers with more significant digits than it should.

You can try to counteract this phenomena by allowing an error margin to the formula:

```
number_format($x, max(2, 3 - ceil(log10(abs($x))) - 1e-8))
```

But this may cause other undesirable effects. You will have to make tests.