# PHP - Rounding Any Number to a Certain Place

Tags: php, rounding

Is there a way to simply round a float to a given precision? For example, if I set the precision as 3, I would like

```
25430.0 to round to 25400.0 -
24.044 to round to 24.0 -
6.496 to round to 6.50 -
0.0006355 to round to 0.000636
```

But between the oddities of float math and my understanding of round() -- that being that you need to specify whether the precision is pre-decimal or post-decimal, plus the need to specify a mode -- I'm just not sure where to begin. I don't want it to care where the decimal is, just plain round whatever number I give it, same as I would with a pencil and paper.

It seems like a pretty standard request, but I'm not able to figure out how to simply round a number. Am I just stuck doing acrobatics to figure out which syntax of round() I need to implement on a case-by-case and then deal with the float weirdness from there?

Comment: Define your logic why `6.494 to round to 6.50`, but `0.0006355 to round to 0.000636`, but not to `0`? And why `25400` is without decimal part, but `24.0` is with decimal part

Comment: How are your given examples showing a precision of 3? Precision is used to give how many numbers before/after the decimal point should remain.

Comment: It looks like you mean something like "significant digits", rather than precision.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  My use of "precision" was imprecise, I guess.  Significant digits may be the better term.

Comment: This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618679/format-number-to-n-significant-digits-in-php) may help you find a solution to your problem.

Comment: I've corrected my own rounding errors in the question through a facepalm.  Thanks Zhorov and Olivier, I think that may do the trick, I'll implement it.  Didn't find it in my searches, but that could be because I was confusing precision with significant digits...